# How do I enable device placement logging (log_device_placement) in TensorFlow 2.n

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

I would like to see which operations run on which device.  In TensorFlow 1.n, a session config could be used (log_device_placement).  Is there a similar operation in TF 2.n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find which operations run on which device, use

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
```

as the first line after importing TensorFlow. More details you can find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu)

Comment: Thank you.  Its a shame that they put it in the "GPU" section.  I was also hoping for better resolution (ie which core an operation was run on) but I understand why that would be harder.